# Binding a nested list into addition columns in xaml

Tags: wpf, xaml, xceed-datagrid

I have a collection that I am binding to a datagrid (the wpf extended toolkit datagrid).  Everything is fine with the standard binding but now I want to bind a nested list in that collection to additional columns.

For example
Person
  Name
  Age
  Birthday
  PhoneNumbers[]

Where Name, age, and person bind perfectly but the person might have many phone numbers so I use a list instead of a single object.  Strictly speaking the "PhoneNumbers" is a type that also stores information like "Home" or "Mobile" and I want that to be the header in a new column.  So the data grid would be something like

Name    Age    Birthday   Home  Mobile  Work

John     42    1/2/1234   1234  5678    9012

etc.  However I dont know in advance how long the nested list will be.  To be clear this is somewhat for learning purposes so I am trying to figure out if it is doable in pure XAML.  I understand I could add the columns at runtime in the code behind. I am not sure it is possible however.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, I think Phone numbers collection cannot be shown side by side with other columns, Instead you need to manage that using [Row details in Datagrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee344869.aspx)